# The renderList sort function is unstable with MeshFaceMaterial

Tags: javascript, three.js

I use Three.js ver. 61
The browsers are Firefox ver. 24.0 and Chrome 30.0.1599.69 m
I tested the app on Windows Xp, 7 and 8.

My problem is always the same (http://jsfiddle.net/eZZ5x/7/):
I'm rendering a prism inside a cylinder.
The cylinder is composed of a series of rings (I used toroids) that correspond to the sections of the prism in yellow. Now when I rotate the object the rings that are located in front are drawn behind sections of the prism that are located behind.

For the prism I used MeshFaceMaterial(materials) where

`materials = [
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffff00, opacity: 0.9, depthWrite: false, depthTest: false, transparent: false, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, side: THREE.DoubleSide}),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000, opacity: 0.6, depthWrite: false, depthTest: false, transparent: true, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, })
            ];`

For the rings and the arrow i used

`material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xC0C0C0, specular: 0xC0C0C0, shininess: 50, combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation});`

I hope I was clear.

Comment: you've given us all the details, but you still need to ask an actual question here

Comment: How does this look to you? http://jsfiddle.net/eZZ5x/8/

Comment: Wow! Works fine!!! I'm seeing your code to understand the changes to be made ...

Comment: Thanks for your invaluable help!